# Migrating From HSQL DB 1.8 to 2.0

Tags: java, hsqldb

Recently I came across this issue. I’m maintaining a software product which was written in Java and HSQLDB is the back end database engine version 1.8. But recently we upgraded HSQLDB version from 1.8 to 2.0.  After that migrating we are getting following error when HSQLDB is running some prepared statements

```
java.sql.SQLException: data exception: string data, right truncation
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Upul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most recent 2.0.1 snapshot releases ([http://hsqldb.org/support](http://hsqldb.org/support/)) there are some further fixes to issues arising in upgrades from older versions. If you still have an issue with the latest versions, please report the details to the HSQLDB project and we will investigate and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I thing, this is bug in this version .. but now a days it fixed...

you can check it with this link 
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2983086&group_id=23316&atid=378131

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but might help the others, this exception is thrown when the maximum length of the field is exceeded by insert or update operations. For my case, I was also updating hsqldb version from 1.8 to 2.4.8 and setting *sql.enforce_strict_size=false* property did not help at all.